Hardware debouncing of 3.3V high signal for an ESP32 turned on via optocoupler
With an optocoupler I detect once a button, a ring bell in that case, is pressed. The ring bell is a 4+n system, I get about +5 to +6 VDC if the ring bell is pressed. It switches an optocoupler which sets a GPIO on an ESP32 on high then:


I am doing that twice, since there is a primary and secondary call.
On the schematics you can see, that I used a capacitor (C4) in the output to debounce the signal. As I don't want to interfere with the input signal too much, I thought it would be better to debounce on the output of the optocoupler. I know that software debouncing is possible, but I thought it would be harmless to debounce it on hardware side as well.
However, a commentor in another question told me:

BitLauncher, Commented, 24th Aug 2024, 22:59: I see no reason for C4 and C5. If you need debouncing of the buttons at the door bell etc. - better make this with a proper circuit - or even debounce in software (see its chapter "Page 17 A Guide to Debouncing Software Debouncers") without any further hardware! U4 and U7 with these C's can create like very little short circuits of 3.3V power supply.

I think he is right if he says that there is no real reason, since software debouncing is possible. I think nowadays one would prefer software over hardware debouncing. However, I thought this would be trivial and especially harmless.
But he especially says that

[...] U4 [= Primary Call Detection] and U7 [= Secondary Call Detection] with these C's can create like very little short circuits of 3.3V power supply.

a) Why is that? How could the 1 µF capacitor (MLCC) cause little short circuits? Is the capacitance too large?
b) How could I fix the schematics? I don't have that much space left.

Look at what happens to supply current if I charge a capacitor directly across a power supply when I close a switch:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here's power supply current measured on ammeter AM1:

That's a huge spike of current limited only by the internal resistance of the power supply (represented by R1 in the box), wiring resistance, switch resistance, and the ESR of the capacitor.
If you consider the transistor inside your opto-isolator to be a switch, then your own circuit very closely resembles the circuit I've shown here, and will have a similar problem. In practice, that transistor (switch) "resistance" is quite high, so the current spike won't be nearly so severe, but it's still potentially an issue.

simulate this circuit
This limits capacitor current to a maximum of:
$$ I_{MAX} = \frac{+3.3V}{R_1} = 3.3mA $$
That is respectably small, easily manageable by the power supply, and won't cause significant supply voltage dips each time the "switch" is closed.
It does mean that it will take roughly \$5\times R_1 \times C_1 = 5ms\$ to fully charge the capacitor, so your opto-coupler LED current pulse will need to be at least that long.
You can reduce R1 to charge the capacitor more quickly, but this will increase charging current too. Also, the current transfer ratio (CTR) of the opto-coupler severely limits transistor current. To obtain 10mA of charging current could require 20mA or so of opto-coupler LED current.
In fact, your circuit as it is will limit capacitor current, for that very reason, CTR. I wouldn't recommend doing this because opto-coupler characteristics will vary from device to device, and I feel it's better to know exactly what current is flowing.

Common collector (AKA emitter follower) is left, common emitter right. I won't include the debouncing elements, this is just to highlight behavioural differences:

simulate this circuit
With the emitter-follower arrangement, when the LED is fully lit, \$V_{OUT}\$ is at a maximum, +3.3V.
The common-emitter configuration inverts. That is, when the LED is lit, \$V_{OUT} = 0V\$, and when there's no LED current, \$V_{OUT}=+3.3V\$.

You mention concepts such as emitter follower and common-emitter -- how does this exist in an isolated supply where there is no "common" potential?   Also, your text "if you configured ... as common-emitter ... :" suggests your schematic snippet is a common-emitter but it, too, "looks like" an emitter follower. But again, I am confused how such concepts can exist in an opto-coupler which has no "common" potential and no true current flow from input to output.

@rohmeooo The emitter and collector can be connected however you like, using either the positive supply or ground. I'll draw examples at the bottom of my answer, with some notes.

@rohmeooo Actually, my apologies, I mislead you. There's no need for common-emitter in this simple application.

i see what you mean now.  There is some inversion and some difference in voltage levels-- certainly worthy of consideration.           I usually use the different transistor configurations (common-emitter vs emitter follower) to highlight differences in performance, such as voltage gain, presence of a miller capacitance -- things of that nature. That was the crux of my question -- those sort of behaviors would not be seen in an opto, in my opinion.  Though, there is almost certainly some capacitance from E-B and C-B which could be uneven and have some "miller" type effect.

Detailed and very interesting answer. After the updated answer, nothing is wrong with my common-collector (emitter follower) arrangement, or should I better move to common-emitter?

@Tintenfisch no need to change to common-emitter, unless the inversion is somehow useful to you. Sometimes we like systems to fail in a predictable state, such as when the opto's LED dies, we want the fail-state output to be permanently high, for which we would use common-emitter. I doubt this is of much concern for you here.

By switching an optocoupler the cap is directly connected to 3v3 source so a “huge” current will initially flow through cap and opto.
(Discharged cap acts as short).
Some resistance should be placed in front of capacitor:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Is the 2K2 the pull-down which in my schematics is the 4K7 (R6)? Isn't the whole pull-down resistance then not 22K + 2K2 (= 24,2K)?

It does not make much sence talk about what pull-down is (i would say 2k2) but rather what impedance is involved in charging /discharging. The cap charges through 22k and discharges through 24.2k. So in both the time costant is almost the same.

Thanks. Just for me to understand your schematics correctly: A) If the optocoupler is switched off, the GPIO is pulled down to GND with 2K2 (after the capacitor is discharged). So I will have a stable low signal. If the optocoupler is switched on, I will get a high signal through 22K resistance + through the capacitor, which is also charged through 22K. -- B) Without hardware unbouncing (no capacitor at all), do I still need the 22K? For me it sounds that I can't at all put the 3.3V on a GPIO without resistance, or is this a wrong assumption?

A) When opto is off the gpio is pulled low through 22k+2k2. When opto is on the gpio is pulled high via 22k. B) Without debouncing just remove C1 & R2 and connect gpio to optos emitter (upper lead of 2k2). No need to worry about, the gpio will see 3v3 only. The gpio input impedance is so high (Mohms) it doesn’t need the resistor in front.

I see, so the short due to the capacitor use would actually only between the optocouplers output and the capacitor. Can this cause damages, even for 100 nF? If 100 nF shouldn't turn out to be working, do you think I could go up to 1 µF, since the debouncing should be as reliable as possible?

Higher cap -> higher chance the opto will be damaged (opto is more critical than cap, or another words the opto will be damaged first). A huge impact has a led current. A higher led current forces higher current through transistor. I think both will survive even with 1uF cap , but it is not a technically and functionally correct solution.

'[...] but it is not a technically and functionally correct solution' => If no resistor between the optocoupler and the capacitor is used, I assume? With my question about the 1 µF I meant an increase of the capacitors capacitance while keeping your schematic.

Yes, it was mean it’s not correct to charge cap without resistor in series in your schematic. When (in my schematic) 100n cap is used the reaction time is about 2ms (Tau=2.2ms). With 1u it is 20ms (Tau=22ms). So pick one according the bouncing significance and duration.

The schemstic is fine but as in another answer it is said that ESP32 has no input hysteresis. If so, a slowly changing signal may be just as bad as non-debounced signal. At least the pin should not be used for interrupts, as it could trigger multiple interrupts when the signal slowly floats right at the threshold between logic 0 and 1. Not many chips tolerate too slow input either, they work best with fast enough edges to be clearly high or low or change quickly between the states.

The circuit you show does not do proper hardware debouncing since the GPIO of the ESP32 do not have Schmitt triggers. It will reduce the number of transitions and may appear to be correct but there will be false counts.
The current through the capacitor will be poorly controlled and will be limited by the CTR of the opto to a fairly low value (less than 15mA peak for that particular opto and input voltage), so I doubt it will be a problem in practice.
Being on the conservative side when it comes to hardware design, I would still add a resistor, but if you want to actually do debouncing, you should add a Schmitt trigger-input gate of some kind (some are available in SOT-23).
If you want to do software debouncing, I suggest polling the input from a ~1ms periodic interrupt. It is generally not a good idea to use a hardware interrupt input for this sort of thing.

If the ESP32 has no Schmitt trigger inputs, then slowing down the signal falling edge with a capacitor is even more poor solution than omitting the capacitor.

@Justme I guess it will replace contact bounce with copious noise near the slow transition.
